# Can I Install a wildcard SSL certificate from a third party to a Hostinger domain?

Tags: web-hosting, https, security-certificate, multi-subdomains

I have a domain registered with Hostinger, along with hosting, which does not support wildcard SSL certificates. Is there any workaround for this issue? Is there any way I can manually install a wildcard ssl to my web app or maybe purchase it from elsewhere, like GoDaddy or Namecheap, and link it to my Hostinger domain?

I have a Laravel web app that uses dynamic subdomains and Hostinger only allows for creation of static subdomains and requires a certificate for each which will not work in my case.

Comment: If you don't control the webserver hosting your content, you can't control how certificates are handled.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the response, can you elaborate a bit more? So I have to change my hosting Provider?

Comment: Have you already set up the wildcard subdomain hosting with SSL at Hostinger?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Hostinger hosting does not support wildcard hosting as mentioned above. They support individual static subdomain and an ssl can be added to each subdomain but the way my project is setup, the subdomain depends on the project name so if I create a project called project1, the subdomain would be project1.myDomain.com. I cannot get individual ssl as I don't know what the subdomain would be as they are generated dynamically or programmatically. The solution would be a wildcard ssl but that is not supported by hostinger.

Comment: I've not used hostinger, but unless hostinger will let you install the cert, you can't get the cert elsewhere and have it magically work with hostinger - as their web server need to add it to their config file.   If you can get the sites to work at Hostinger using an invalid cert or http, you can likely use a reverse proxy of some sort (?maybe even something like Cloudflare?) to work around your problem, but frankly it sounds like hostinger is simply not the appropriate provider for your needs - so you are likely to be better served finding a provider that can do what you need.